# When statement failed compilation in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, compilation, conditional-statements, pipeline, dsl

I'm trying to use the **when** statement in stage block as it is written in official documentations but it fails saying : **No such DSL method 'when' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook ...**

Just below, the sample code as it is written in the jenkins pipeline field of the simple pipeline job:

```
node() {
    stage('test when') {
        when { 
            expression { "tata" == "tata" }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'echo toto'
        }
    }
}
```

I've also found this code and tried it but it has answered: **No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook,...**

```
node() {
    stage('test when') {
        steps {
            sh 'echo toto'
        }
        when { 
            expression { "tata" == "tata" }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have two questions:
1) Is this could be a missing plugin problem ?
2) Is there a Reference that shows the parenthood/childiness of every pipeline blocks ?

and at least, could you give me an idea about where to look from?
Thanks you
PS: I saw that my previous question has been edited. English is not my native language, sorry.